# c++ freeing memory in priority_queue

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, free

I have a

```
priority_queue<node*, std::vector<node*>, CompareNodes> heap;
```

Let's say the node consists of:

```
class node {
public:
    int value;
    int key;
    int order = 1000000;
};
```

How do I free the memory after i'm done with the priority queue? 
My approach doesn't seem to be working:

```
while (heap.top()) {

        node * t = heap.top();
        heap.pop();
        delete t;
    }
```

Comment: What tells you it isn't working? Also, it looks like this will always throw if there's no NULL elements.

Comment: Describing a problem as "doesn't seem to be working" isn't helpful. What *exactly* goes wrong?

Comment: Please post [mcve](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I meant the program triggers a breakpoint and shuts down

Comment: There's nothing in your code to indicate you have to free any memory. Better post an [mcve].

Comment: @Simon Then you probably put some address into the queue that's not legal to `delete`. You can only `delete` what you `new`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you'll want to do something more like this:

```
while (!heap.empty())
{ /* the rest ... */ }
```

If the heap is empty, `.top()` will throw an exception because there's nothing to return, which will happen when you are popping elements.

Also, if available you should use

```
priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<node>, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>>, CompareNodes> heap;
```

so you don't have to worry about clearing the memory yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just like most std:: containers, the memory may or may not be freed when you want it to be. Memory is usually kept around for a longer time so that when you perform a heap.push or equivalent operation, the memory doesn't need to be allocated again.

Think of std::vector which has to allocate a new set of memory for the entire vector each time it grows (vector data must be contiguous in memory). It is more efficient for std::vector to perform a large one time allocation and keep the memory around so that the growth operation  doesn't kill performance -- a) allocate new space big enough, b) copy entire contents of existing vector to new vector space, c) delete the old vector space.

Bottom line is you can't force it to free memory for individual items.

Comment: He's using `std::vector<node*>` not `std::vector<node>`

Comment: std::vector<node *> still requires all memory cells for all pointers to be contiguous in memory. The example of std::vector still applies to std::priority_queue in that he can't free the memory std::priority_queue allocates.

Comment: Yes but he's not trying to delete the pointers, he's deleting what they're pointing at.

Comment: I interpreted the question to ask "how can I free the memory that is allocated by std::priority_queue". Not how can I free the node memory because his code calls delete for that memory.

Comment: @Russ sorry, I meant to free the memory allocated by the nodes